# bash:no such file or directory

Tags: bash

```
dhruvhadoop1@hadoopmaster:~$ cat /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
bash: /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory
dhruvhadoop1@hadoopmaster:~$ cat /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/hadoopuser/ .ssh/authorized_keys
bash: /home/hadoopuser/: Is a directory
dhruvhadoop1@hadoopmaster:~$ cat /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/hadoopuser/ .ssh/authorized_keys/
bash: /home/hadoopuser/: Is a directory
dhruvhadoop1@hadoopmaster:~$ cat /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
bash: /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory
dhruvhadoop1@hadoopmaster:~$
```

Comment: Please add more details as just pasting some code into a question doesn't at all help us help you at all

Answer (score 1):

The `.ssh` directory and it's files have strict access permissions: The files are only readable/writable by the owner (or root). If you are not `hadoopuser`, then you'll have to:

```
sudo sh -c 'cat /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

The error message is a bit misleading. You're trying to append, so the shell has to check if the authorized_keys file exists. You don't have read permission on the .ssh directory, so the shell cannot complete that check.

Comment: What makes you think the OP is not the hadoop user? That should produce a "permission denied", right? Also, won't what you are suggesting break the ssh authentication since the files will not belong to the hadoop user? I get the expected "permission denied" error on my system.

Comment: Mostly, his prompt.

Comment: @glennjackman ah, good point, I missed that. Still, I tried a similar thing on my system and got a permission denied error. What would result in the "no such file" error? Also, doesn't this break `ssh` since the `authorized_keys` file won't be owned by `hadoopuser`? Isn't it more likely there is simply no `.ssh` directory?

Comment: I'm also getting permission denied. Let's see if @Dhruv supplies any further information

Comment: nevermind, he posted a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

The *.ssh* folder are not exist because you haven't created any key yet.
you must first create your key like this:

```
ssh-keygen
```

and enter any question that shell asked.
after this you have *.ssh* folder in your home.

Answer (score -2):

Most of the error messages you posted are because you are not using the correct path as you have added a space in various locations or specified a directory rather then a file.

The only error message of any real relevance is

> /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/authorized_keys: **No such file or directory**

You can not append a non-existant file so either copy the file (preferred method)

```
cp /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

or create the file with a single `>`

```
cat /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub > /home/hadoopuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: "You can not append a non-existant file" -- wrong. The >> redirection will create the file if it does not exist.